# How to add duplicate values in the foreign key column in another table?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, duplicates, foreign-keys

Once I put the constraint in the another table for setting the foreign key, I can't insert a duplicate value into the table.

1. remove the foreign key constraint in the referencing table (in the purchase table), then how can I make relationships between the referenced and referencing tables?
2. Probably allowing duplicate values ? which I do not know how to do it?

**Purchase** table:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase 
(
    [PurchaseId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [SupplierId] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES supplier(SupplierId),
    [ProductId] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES product (ProductId),
    [NumberReceived] INT NOT NULL,
    [PurchaseDate] DATE NOT NULL,
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT purchase ON
INSERT INTO purchase ([PurchaseId], [SupplierId], [ProductId], [NumberReceived], [PurchaseDate])
VALUES (1, 2, 2, 50, '2014-11-02'),
       (2, 2, 1, 15, '2014-09-02'),

SET IDENTITY_INSERT purchase OFF
```

Trigger: change the inventory value

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Incoming_Stock
ON purchase 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Inserted_Value INT, @ProductId INT, @Updated_value INT

    SELECT @Inserted_Value, @ProductId(SELECT NumberReceived, ProductId 
    FROM inserted)

    UPDATE product 
    SET InventoryOnHand = InventoryOnHand + @Inserted_Value 
    WHERE ProductId = @ProductId
END
```

I am trying to add duplicate values to purchase table and getting the error of duplicate foreign key values.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT purchase ON

INSERT INTO purchase ([PurchaseId], [SupplierId], [ProductId], [NumberReceived], [PurchaseDate])
VALUES (1, 2, 2, 50, '2014-11-02')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT purchase OFF
```

Comment: is it duplicate identity column or duplicate row excluding identity column ?

Comment: Sorry, I overthought about it at the moment. The problem now I have is trigger is not working because I am selecting instead of setting.

Comment: And you have also made a very common mistake - assuming a single row was affected by the insert (or merge) statement that cause the trigger to execute. You have much to learn - and that includes best practices for writing tsql and writing technical questions. There is no tsql error that is similar to "error of duplicate foreign key values". Perhaps that is a translation issue, but it is your burden to post clear and accurate details about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking this. You've specified `PurchaseId` as an Identity column and the primary key, and then in your second insert statement you're explicity specifying the `PurchaseId` to be `1` which  conflicts with the primary key value already inserted in your first insert statement.

`PurchaseId` needs to be unique.

Comment: Sorry about my stupidity. My trigger seems not working here. I will figure out why